# CSS Responsive Hover Imagecaption with Zoom

Tags: css, hover, zooming, responsive, caption

I made this Code for an Image Grid which is responsive and zooms in on the image and shows its caption. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to make Caption responsive. The Dark Overlay with the Blur Class should be the same size as the image as the text should stay in the middle. But as soon as I change position:absolute and or change the width and height to auto or 100% the Elements disappear.

I haven't coded in a while am i missing something obvious? Any idea how to fix this?

[Example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPOvrO)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="columns"> 
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="blur"></div>
        <div class="caption-text">
            <h5>Info 1</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>  
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
 </div>
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
</div>

.column{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column:hover .caption{
    opacity: 1;
}

.column:hover img{
opacity: 1;
transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.15,1.15);
-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.15,1.15);
-moz-transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.15,1.15);
-ms-transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.15,1.15);
-o-transform: rotate(3deg) scale(1.15,1.15);

-moz-transform-origin: center;
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
transform-origin: center;
}

.column img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
    width:100%;
}

.column .caption{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
}

.column img{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.column .blur{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.column .caption-text h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.column .caption-text{
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    top:100px;
}

/* Grid */
* { 
box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
max-width: 1200px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}    
.columns {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
margin:-1.5%;

}

.column {
position: relative;
width:50%;

flex: 32%;
overflow:hidden;
margin: 5px;
&:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
&:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
.columns .column {

    flex-basis: 40%;
    &:nth-last-child(2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    &:last-child {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
.columns .column {
    flex-basis: 100%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` to solve it changing/adding these properties in your CSS:

```
.column .blur {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;  
}
.column .caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.column .caption-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Since `.column .blur` and `.column .caption-text` have similarities, you could create a `class` for both.

Final result in here: https://jsfiddle.net/b42ehq8o

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cool Solutions, did not think about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of changed that were made to achieve your results, described in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwyGrm?editors=1100)

To vertically center, I've used `flex`

```
.column .caption-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
...
```

and on your `h5` text

```
.column .caption-text h5{
    max-width:50%
    ...
 }
```

Your div(s) that are

```
<div class="caption">
<div class="blur"></div>
<div class="caption-text">
```

Their height and width should be `100%`

```
like.column .blur{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.caption{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.column .caption-text h5{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index:99;
    max-width:50%
}

.column .caption-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like you both had the same idea. Cool Solution. Couldn't come up with this

Comment: @iRe happy to help